# Показать список идентификаторов студентов, которые имеют пересдачи

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть колонки id студента, предмета, оценка, дата

```
    select student_id
    from exam_marks
    where subj_id>1
```

Comment: Используйте группировку (Group By) и подсчет количества по полю (Count).

Comment: Вы бы хоть указали, как определяется, что имеется пересдача

Comment: В текущей постановке задачи непонятно, какое условие нужно проверять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала необходимо посчитать сколько всего у студента было предметов *(количество уникальных значений)*  с помощью `DICTINCT` в конструкции `COUNT`. Затем посмотреть количество экзаменов которые он посетил. Если это число превышает число предметов, значит у него была хотя бы одна пересдача.

```
select s.student_id ,count(distinct s.subj_id_id )
  from exam_marks as s
    group by s.student_id
      having 
      count(distinct s.subj_id )<count( s.subj_id )
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь

Answer (score 2):

По простому без HAVING так:

```
select student_id 
  from (
        select student_id, exam_id, count(1) cnt
          from exam_marks
         group by student_id, exam_id)
 where cnt > 1
```

, с HAVING:

```
select student_id, exam_id, count(1) cnt
from exam_marks
group by student_id, exam_id)
having cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться следующим запросом

```
SELECT
  student_id,
  COUNT(subj_id) AS total
FROM
  exam_marks
GROUP BY
  student_id
HAVING
  total > 1
```